# ng-include is not working with node.js server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, mean-stack

I have create a simple page using angular.js and node.js server, ng-include is not working.
console error: 404 (not found)

index.html

```
<html>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="">
<div ng-include="'views/header.htm'"></div>

<h1>heading one</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

header.htm

```
  <h1>heading one</h1>
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser =  require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/' + 'index.html');
console.log("----------------");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

OutPut

```
  heading one
```

Answer (score 0):

404 indicate the file is not existing. make sure the HTML file exist in given path. Also, there is a typo error. should be `views/header.html`

```
<div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
```

Comment: when i am using ng-include with node.js getting an error console 404 not found

Comment: i have already used this
    ` <div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div> `

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the right way but it works. Add another get method for the html file which is to be included.

index.html

```
<html>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="">
<div ng-include="'/header'" method="GET"></div>
<h1>heading one</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser =  require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/' + 'index.html');
console.log("----------------");
});
app.get('/header', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/' + 'header.html');
console.log("----------------");
});
app.listen(3000);
```

If any suggestions/corrections/better methods, I would like to know please.